# How to write concat query for multiple 'select into' statement in mysql stored procedures?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to assign values to variables in mysql stored procedures. Here is my code

```
declare count int;
declare ParamOrgId int;
declare isPremium int;

SET @sql = CONCAT(' select count(id) , orgid , (select id from org_subscription t where t.orgid=mainOrgID)  into ', @count,',',ParamOrgId ,',',isPremium ,' '
 from ', tableA );

PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;


SELECT concat('my val is ', ParamOrgId);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIMPLY use user defined variales instead of variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` (IN tableA varchar(255))
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT(' select count(id) , orgid , (select id from org_subscription t where t.orgid=mainOrgID)  into @count,@ParamOrgId ,@isPremium  from ', tableA );

PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;


SELECT concat('my val is ', @ParamOrgId);
END
```

But this only works if you get only 1 result row. IF you want more, you need a Loop

Comment: how can I execute this inside a loop?

Comment: that can_'t be explained in a comment see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ and try it and if you have a problem, write a new question